# ¿Cómo migrar los "datos" de bases de datos sqlite3 a MySQL en Django?

Tags: base-de-datos, django

estoy intentando migrar los **datos** que tengo en la base de datos default de Django (db.sqlite3) a una base de datos MySQL, pero al aplicar los comandos de migración (*python manage.py makemigrations, python manage.py migrate*), solo crea las tablas en la DD.BB MySQL pero vacías, hay alguna forma de hacerlo?
Adjunto capturas.
[image: Base de datos creada con el comando migrate]

[image: Configuración de base de datos]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una posible solución básica y rápida es jugar con comandos `dumpdata` y `loaddata`.

A lo que estas llamando migraciones **no son migraciones de datos**, sino de **Esquemas de base de datos**. Las `migraciones` son instrucciones de un sistema que va siguiendo los cambios de los `models` de tu proyecto, para posteriormente tratarlo con los Sistemas de BD.

#### Solución

Partimos de la base que tienes configurado el Django con sqlite, y que ya tienes un servidor Mysql listo y con accesso.

1. `./manage.py dumpdata --output data.json`
2. Cambia de motor de DB, edita el fichero `settings.py`
3. `./manage.py loaddata data.json`

Para más información o casualisticas determinadas : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/

PD:

- He utilizado comando `./manage.py` para simplificar però deberia usarse con el `django-admin`
- Si tienes problemas con la continuidad de als migraciones, managers personalizados es probable que tengas problemas...

Comment: gracias, agregar que tuve que usar el comando `./manage.py dumpdata --exclude auth.permission --exclude contenttypes > db.json`